# How do I remove extra whitespaces created by iniparser?

Tags: c, file, embedded, ini

Recently I'm taking [iniparser](https://github.com/ndevilla/iniparser) as primary choice. However, with its API creating too many whitespaces resulting in waste of memory.

For example, `iniparser_set()` will create

```
/*test.ini*/
[section]
key                               = value
```

instead

```
/*test.ini*/
[section]
key = value
```

From the point of embedded system's view, removing those extra whitespaces is a great thing for saving memory space. So, how to fix it?

Comment: I see this line in `iniparser_dumpsection_ini` function: `fprintf(f, "%-30s = %s\n", d->key[j]+seclen+1, d->val[j] ? d->val[j] : "");`. As you can see, key is printed with format specifier `%-30s`. Maybe that is the issue.

Comment: Unrelated: It's kind of correct that writing code for small embedded systems require you to avoid wasting memory/cpu cycles/etc. But are you really sure that a few extra space in an ini-file is worth your time?

Comment: @4386427 Yes, because it will be like 100+ ini files

Comment: You could clone the sources and correct the offending printf as pointed out by @kiner_shah. Or, knowing the internals, you can dump the data by yourself, without using the original function. Generating inifiles is easy, may be you can avoid to use the library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the source code of iniparser (https://github.com/ndevilla/iniparser/blob/deb85ad4936d4ca32cc2260ce43323d47936410d/src/iniparser.c#L312):

in `iniparser_dumpsection_ini` function, there is this line:

```
fprintf(f,
    "%-30s = %s\n",
    d->key[j]+seclen+1,
    d->val[j] ? d->val[j] : "");
```

As you can see, key is printed with format specifier `%-30s` which is probably causing this issue.

So, you can clone the repo source code and make the changes. Example, replace format specifier with `%s`, like:

```
fprintf(f,
    "%s = %s\n",        // CHANGE HERE
    d->key[j]+seclen+1,
    d->val[j] ? d->val[j] : "");
```